# How to CAST empty array value of an ANYARRAY-function to ANYARRAY?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I am using pgv10. The function that I need seems this **wrong** function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_coalesce(ANYARRAY) RETURNS ANYARRAY AS $f$
  SELECT CASE WHEN $1 IS NULL THEN array[]::ANYARRAY ELSE $1 END;
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

---

**Curiosity**

... I started to simplify a complex problem, and arrives in the test `select coalesce(null::text[], array[]::text[])` that *not* worked... So it was a good question, how to implement it? But sorry, I do something workng, *COALESCE(array,array)* is working fine (phew!).

So, "coalesce problem" is merely illustrative/didatic. What I really want to understand here is:
   **How to use `ANYARRAY`?**

---

PS: other curiosity, the string `concat()`, `||`  and other concatenation operators in PostgreSQL do some "coalescing",

```
 select concat(NULL::text, 'Hello', NULL::text); -- 'Hello'
 select null::text[] || array[]::text[]; -- []
 select array[]::text[] || null::text[]; -- []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use anyarray?

It's an interesting issue, in the context of the usage described in the question. The only way I know is to use an argument as a variable. It's possible in plpgsql (not in plain sql) function:

```
create or replace function array_coalesce(anyarray) 
returns anyarray as $f$
begin
    if $1 is null then
        select '{}' into $1;
    end if;
    return $1;
end 
$f$ language plpgsql immutable;

select array_coalesce(null::int[]);

 array_coalesce 
----------------
 {}
(1 row)
```

By the way, you can simply use `coalesce()` for arrays:

```
select coalesce(null::text[], '{}'::text[]);

 coalesce 
----------
 {}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks (!). The question was confuse but you understand. Yes, *COALESCE()* is working fine, I edited with better title and commenting that is an illustration.